# module.save() Error 'TypeError: this __dict__ descriptor does not support '_DictWrapper' objects'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pycharm

I'm following a tutorial on Youtube for image classification with machine learning. I keep getting the error as shown in the title from trying to save a deep learning module with tensorflow.

I'm using PyCharm on Windows 11.

here is my code...

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as ker

(training_images, training_labels), (testing_images, testing_labels) = ker.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
testing_images, testing_images = training_images / 255, testing_images / 255

class_names = ['Plane', 'Car', 'Bird', 'Cat', 'Deer', 'Dog', 'Frog', 'Horse', 'Ship', 'Truck']

for i in range(16):
    plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow(training_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[training_labels[i][0]])

plt.show()

training_images = training_images[:20000]
training_labels = training_labels[:20000]
testing_images = testing_images[:4000]
testing_labels = testing_labels[:4000]

#Model
model = ker.models.Sequential()
model.add(ker.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(ker.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(ker.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ker.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(ker.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ker.layers.Flatten())
model.add(ker.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(ker.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=1, validation_data=(testing_images, testing_labels))

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(testing_images, testing_labels)
print(f"Loss: {loss}")
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy}")

model.save('img_classifier.model')

#model = ker.models.load_model()
```

the output...

```
C:\img_classifier\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:\img_classifier\main.py 
625/625 [==============================] - 15s 23ms/step - loss: 2.1824 - accuracy: 0.2874 - val_loss: 2.3014 - val_accuracy: 0.1047
125/125 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 2.3014 - accuracy: 0.1047
Loss: 2.30141019821167
Accuracy: 0.10474999994039536
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _update_step_xla while saving (showing 4 of 4). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\{user}\PycharmProjects\img_classifier\main.py", line 47, in <module>
    model.save('img_classifier.model')
  File "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\data_structures.py", line 823, in __getattribute__
    return super().__getattribute__(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: this __dict__ descriptor does not support '_DictWrapper' objects

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried changing IDE's, originally I was using VSCode but had way more errors, then I switched to PyCharm and this is the only error that persists. As you can see, the code for training the module has no issues, but I cannot save the module afterwards.

How can I fix this??

Comment: I have the same error, I am using joblib.dump(model, 'img_classifier.model').

Answer (score 12):

could you check which version of the package wrapt is installed?
I had the same issue using tf2onnx for model optimizing. The problem came out of no where, as the same code worked only days before.
I pinned the problem down to one unfrozen dependency (I think in tensorflow):
You should be able to solve the problem by installing wrapt in version 1.14.1, while tensorflow would install the most recent version 1.15.0 by default.

```
pip install wrapt==1.14.1
```

I'd be happy to hear if i could help you.

As an alternative solution you can set the environment variable WRAPT_DISABLE_EXTENSIONS to true (before the wrapt module is imported).
This is from the wrapt developer in an [issue](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/issues/231) on the wrapt github  repo.
There are actually several users having issues with this. On the tensorflow repo [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/59869) is about your error and the solution so far is to add wrapt<1.15 as requirement in the current tf nightlys.

Background:

I am using tf2onnx in a Databricks environment to optimize tf models by converting them to onnx. Had the same issue with the following requirements:

- opencv-python==4.7.0.68
- segmentation-models==1.0.1
- tensorflow==2.7.4
- numpy ==1.24.2
- tensorflow-addons==0.15.0
- pandas==1.3.5
- Pillow==9.4.0
- scikit-image==0.18.3
- tqdm==4.62.3
- fire==0.5.0
- tf2onnx==1.12.1

```
File "/databricks/conda/envs/mlflow-.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/data_structures.py", line 828, in __getattribute__
        return super(_DictWrapper, self).__getattribute__(name)
    TypeError: this __dict__ descriptor does not support '_DictWrapper' objects
```

By adding the requirement wrapt==1.14.1 I was able to solve this issue:

```
wrapt==1.14.1
```